# Use 52/56oz liquid soap refill bottles directly?

Tags: efficiency

I recently bought some 52/56oz liquid soap refill bottles and want to use them directly instead of following the normal (messy and tedious) process of pouring them into 7.5oz dispensers. What's the most efficient/reasonable way to do this?

I found [https://www.amazon.com/Never-Mt-Soap-Dispenser-Kit/dp/B002FJ9LBS](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002FJ9LBS) and similar products which appear to work well, but, as the first review notes "Great idea although, not $29 for $5.00 worth of plastic".

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to *pour* the liquid soap into the smaller bottles, and it doesn't need to be messy.

See if you can find a "pump top" from another bottle that is mostly / entirely clean. Remove it from the other bottle, clean off the stem of it (which is like a thick straw), and put the end in a glass or bowl of water to pump some water through it and clean it more thoroughly.

[image]

Then, open your 52/56 oz. soap container and dunk the stem (temporarily) in the liquid soap. Put an open 7.5 oz. bottle under the pump, then pump it to dispense the soap cleanly into it. You may need to enlist a friend to help hold the pump top in place as you pump.

Remove the pump top after you're done, clean it off, and store it for your next refill.

Comment: Have you actually tried this? I can see all sorts of reasons it wouldn't work, but, if you've done it, I'll give it a try and let you know what happens.

Comment: Not exactly this, but I have put a pump top into a different bottle and pumped a different fluid with it. Can't remember specifically, but I do remember doing it.

Answer (score 1):

For the liquid soap brands I'm familiar with, refills have a narrower neck than the dispenser bottles.

If there's plenty of soap in the refill container, quickly insert the neck of the refill into the dispenser and gently squeeze the refill container until the dispenser is about half to two-thirds full (this leaves room inside the dispenser for the pump mechanism). Then tilt the assembly slightly and scrape the lip of the refill against the lip of the dispenser as you separate the containers for a quick and clean separation. If you start letting up on the squeeze just before separation, the gentle suction produced helps to hold in the contents of the refill.

If there's less than half a bottle of soap left in the refill, leave the dispenser on the table, insert the neck of the refill into the dispenser, and leave them there until all the soap has been transferred.

Comment: OK, I'll try to post images and more details shortly, but I'm using SoftSoap, and the 56oz refill necks are quite a bit wider than the 7.5 oz dispenser necks (also Softsoap). The refills do have a small hole in the lid so you can invert and squeeze, but the "liquid" is fairly thick, so it's hard to stop at exactly the amount you want and the liquid sometimes clings to the dispenser bottle during separation. Of course, my main goal is still to use the large dispensers directly, since they'll last longer, not just because refills are messy.

Answer (score 1):

Use a funnel.

I personally have never had this problem on my SoftSoap refills. The big bottles have a small squirt port in the cap, so I remove the pump in the small bottles, place the squirt hole directly onto the opening of the pump bottle, and refill.

Edit:
Upon re-reading your question, I realize you are asking for a way to use the actual large bottle instead of the little bottle. I think this would be the last option. Refilling should be easy; I just refilled mine this past weekend and it took all of two minutes. I have had great success with SoftSoap bottles and the Kroger competitor; I can't speak for other off brands

Answer (score 1):

You can use funnel to fill soap dispenser. There are various sizes of funnel available you can choose funnel according to hole of your soap dispenser.

[image: fill dispenser using funnel]
[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's a beautiful image of pouring soap there. In my situation, the soap is more viscous and tends to stick to the pouring bottle or be diverted from its path by static, but a funnel should help w/ some of that.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following steps

- Make a hole on the cap of refill bottle
- Insert one end of this [type pipe](https://4.imimg.com/data4/YN/QO/MY-9301476/white-transparent-pipe-500x500.png) into it so that it immerses to the bottom
- Open the cap of liquid soap bottle and put the other end of tube into this.
- You will get a connected figure like [this](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT4oxjFAegd5m9BnUEiqHQLQaWdQwzPQCNVuVQhBITAknFAxsaO).
- Now press the refill keeping it at a higher position.
- You will find the liquid moving down to other bottle.

You can also go the below type of tube as well, rest procedures are same.
[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell from the linked image (not the one you inlined), but must the tube fill the larger bottle's opening perfectly? If not, some of the soap from the larger refill bottle might spill out? In real life, I just ended up doing this the normal way. It's not too messy if you're careful, and, if you do spill it, it IS soap after all, so not a huge deal.

Comment: @barrycarter As you know, there is no solution as carefree, if you connect it right, everything goes fine.